# Convert CSV to WordPress importable XML format

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have some data in CSV format and I want to import this data into wordpress users and it have more than 6k entries.

Is there any possible way to convert **CSV format into XML** so i can import into wordpress.

I also created some extra custom fields for user profile, 
like

- Membership ID
- Address,
- City,
- Phone,
- Mobile,
- Occupation

etc

**CSV format is following**

```
'date','membership id','address','city','phone','mobile','occupation'
'','ABCD00-01','this is the address','city of member','phone of member','mobile of member','occupation of member'
'','ABCD00-02','this is the address','city of member','phone of member','mobile of member','occupation of member'
'','ABCD00-03','this is the address','city of member','phone of member','mobile of member','occupation of member'
```

Comment: Wordpress has some plugins to import CSV: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/ , try to use them, is much easier

Answer (score 0):

You can import the bulk of users with the following plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/

It also has the following features

- Import CSV file with users directly to your WordPress
- Import thousends of users in only some seconds
- You can also import meta-data like data from WooCommerce customers using the correct meta_keys
- Send a mail to every new user
- Use your own
- You can also update data of each user
- Assing a role
- Create a cron task to import users periodically
- Edit the metadata (you will be able to edit the metadata imported using meta keys directly in the profile of each user)
- Read our documentation
- Ask anything in support forum, we try to give the best support